# Computing a closed formula for a recurrent sequence using eigen -values and -vectors

Tags: sequences-and-series, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, diagonalization

How would you use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to compute a closed formula for the following sequence: $$\{x_0=1, x_1=2, x_n=5x_{n-1} + 14x_{n-2}, n \ge 0 \}$$

I have come up with the following formula: $$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
14 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{n-2}\\
x_{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{n}\\
x_{n+1}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So to compute x_n I want to take the n'th power of the matrix A: $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
14 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$ and multiply it with the "starting state" vector: $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}$.
Therefore I used the theory that $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix holding eigenvalues for $A$ along its diagonal and $P$ is the matrix holding the corresponding eigenvectors for the eigenvalues in $A$.

I computed the eigenvalues and vectors for $A$ and got that $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{-1}{7}
\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 7$. And $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_2 = -2$.

So filling out the formula $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
14 & 5
\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
\frac{-1}{7} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
7^n & 0 \\
0 & -2^n
\end{bmatrix} * \frac{9}{14} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & -1 \\
\frac{1}{7} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which when multiplied gives: $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
14 & 5
\end{bmatrix}^n=\frac{9}{14} * \begin{bmatrix}
7^n*\frac{1}{2}+(-2)^n
*\frac{1}{7} & -9^n \\
-\frac{1}{7}*7^n*\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{7}*-2^n & \frac{1}{7}*-7^n+\frac{1}{2}*-2^n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The problem is now that when I multiply the result onto the "starting vector" $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ I get the this formula for $x_n$: $\frac{9}{14}((7^n+\frac{1}{2}+(-2)^n*\frac{1}{7})+(2*(-9)^n))$

Which doesn't give the correct answer when checking for $n=2$ for example: $\frac{9}{14}((7^2+\frac{1}{2}+(-2)^2*\frac{1}{7})+(2*(-9)^2)) = \frac{26721}{196}$.
For $n=2$ I would expect $x_2=5*2 + 14*1=24$.

Can anyone help me figure out where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use eigenvalues/eigenvectors? This is a linear difference equation for which you can easily identify a basis for the solution space. Looking at the roots of the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 -5 \lambda -14$, any solution is of the form
$$
x_n = c_1 \cdot (-2)^n + c_2 \cdot 7^n
$$

Now you can just compute $c_1, c_2$ from the initial condition $x_0 = 1$ and $x_1=2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried finding the initial vector $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ as a linear combination of $A$'s eigenvectors. I then multiplied matrix $A^n$ onto this linear combination ($A^n*(c_1*v_1+c_2*v_2)$) and still got back a vector for $x_2$ that was no way near 24 in the first row. 
In your approach would you compute $c_1, c_2$ by solving the system: 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1\\2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-2&0\\0&7
\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\c_2
\end{bmatrix} $$